# First ReplaceAll, then evaluate an expression

Tags: evaluation, replacement

Here is a simple example using `ReplaceAll`:

```
rvec[[2]] /. rvec -> {x, y}
```

I think Mathematica first tries to evaluate `rvec[[2]]`, realising this is not a list, and only afterwards uses `ReplaceAll`. The warning output confirms this.

If instead of `rvec[[2]]` we have some complex expression (e.g. inversion of a matrix), Mathematica will to do it analytically first before making the substitution. This is not what I intend, I want to delay the evaluation of `rvec[[2]]` (or other more complex things in its place) until the `ReplaceAll` substitution has been done.

How can I tell Mathematica to substitute first, then evaluate?

Comment: `With[{rvec = {x,y}}, rvec[[2]]]`?

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, is it possible to keep my form (with a subsitution list) more or less intact? My rvec is really many expressions, and {x,y} a long substitution list.

Comment: I think it's best if you include a MWE where my trick above is inconvenient, and where a substitution really is required. Otherwise I'm not sure why you would want to do things your way (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346882)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated):

```
Unevaluated[rvec[[2]]] /. rvec->{x,y}
```

> y

Answer (score 4):

You can also hold then release:

```
Hold[rvec[[2]]] /. rvec -> {x, y} // ReleaseHold
```

> y

Pattern replacement works through hold.

Answer (score 1):

```
(rvec /. rvec -> {x, y})[[2]]
```